# Heroku postgres follower has more tables

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Just created a follower Heroku postgres database. The follower seems to have more tables than the 'master'. Why?

`$ heroku pg:info`

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_XXXX_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Ronin
Status:      Available
Data Size:   3.12 GB
Tables:      56
PG Version:  9.3.4
Connections: 20
Fork/Follow: Available
Rollback:    Unsupported
Created:     2014-07-12 21:35 UTC
Followers:   HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YYYY
Maintenance: not required
```

=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YYYY_URL
Plan:            Premium 2
Status:          Available
Data Size:       5.05 GB
Tables:          70
PG Version:      9.3.5
Connections:     2
Fork/Follow:     Unavailable on followers
Rollback:        earliest from 2014-08-20 05:56 UTC
Created:         2014-08-27 05:47 UTC
Data Encryption: In Use
Following:       HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_XXXX
Behind By:       72755 commits
Maintenance:     not required

Note: My original db plan is now legacy, so I had to create my follower with a different, larger db plan.

My app's operation isn't unduly affected, but I'm curious about the table number discrepancy. Also, if I hit-swap this follower to become primary, will the table count go from `70` to `56`?

Comment: No idea about heroku but "Behind By: 72755 commits" seems to give you an idea why there are not the same amount of tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What DrColossos said in the comments; your database is behind in commits, something is blocking it from applying the upstream changes. You can install the [pg-extras](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras) plugin and examine your follower database:

`$ heroku pg:locks HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YYY_URL -a app_name`

That should show you some information on locks that could be preventing your database from catching up. If it's still 72k or more commits behind, I imagine you'll find a very old lock in place.

Comment: Sure enough. Follower is all caught up and table count is the same now. Thanks!